# problema con tipo de variable en php twitch auth api

Tags: php, json, array

estoy utilizando el ejemplo de la api de twitch para autenticarse con php (https://github.com/TwitchDev/authentication-samples/tree/master/php), el problema que tengo actualmente es recuperar la información que me retorna la api no se si es un array o un objecto json, me interesa obtener el email, diplay_name y el profile_image_url, pero el ejemplo presenta errores, por lo que al hacer un var dump a la variable $user, me retorna esto

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(8) "123456987" ["login"]=> string(5) "userprueba" ["display_name"]=> string(5) "userprueba" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["broadcaster_type"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["profile_image_url"]=> string(113) "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/user-default-pictures/0ecbb6c3-fecb-4016-8115-aa467b7c36ed-profile_image-300x300.jpg" ["offline_image_url"]=> string(0) "" ["view_count"]=> int(82) ["email"]=> string(23) "emailprueba@gmail.com" } } }
```

y la forma que tengo es la siguiente

```
echo '<html><table>';
        echo '<tr><th>Access Token</th><td>' . htmlspecialchars($accessToken->getToken()) . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Refresh Token</th><td>' . htmlspecialchars($accessToken->getRefreshToken()) . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Username</th><td>' . htmlspecialchars($user['display_name']) . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>email</th><td>' . htmlspecialchars($user['email']) . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Image</th><td><img src="' . htmlspecialchars($user['profile_image_url']) . '"></td></tr>';
        echo '</table></html>';
```

con ese codigo recibo los siguientes errores:

```
Notice: Undefined index: display_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Twitch\index.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: bio in C:\xampp\htdocs\Twitch\index.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: profile_image_url in C:\xampp\htdocs\Twitch\index.php on line 46
```

pertencientes a las 3 ultimas filas de la tabla, que son las variables que mencione en un principio.

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione haciendo esto:

```
$user=$user['data'];
$user=$user[0];
```

y luego pude acceder a los datos asi:

```
echo $user['email'];
```